# How to compare DataGridView cell data to DataSet cell data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2013, dataset

In a VB.NET WinForms project I'm working on in VS2013 I am detecting when the user changes something in a cell on the CellValueChanged event. When a row in the DataGridView is found that is different from the DataSet I highlight the row in pink.

In my code though, I only know how to iterate through **all** of the rows, rather than just compare the row that fired the CellValueChanged event to the DataSet.

Here's my current code:

```
Private Sub dgvEmployees_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvEmployees.CellValueChanged
    ' Pass the row and cell indexes to the method so we can change the color of the edited row
    CompareDgvToDataSource(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub CompareDgvToDataSource(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal columnIndex As Integer)

    ' Force ending Edit mode so the last edited value is committed
    EmployeesBindingSource.EndEdit()

    Dim dsChanged As DataSet = EmployeesDataSet.GetChanges()

    If Not dsChanged Is Nothing Then
        For Each dt As DataTable In dsChanged.Tables
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                    Dim currentColor As System.Drawing.Color = dgvEmployees.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor

                    If Not row(i, DataRowVersion.Current).Equals(row(i, DataRowVersion.Original)) Then
                        Console.WriteLine("Row index: " & dt.Rows.IndexOf(row))
                        ' This works
                        dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink
                    Else
                        ' Need to change the BackColor back to what it should be based on its original alternating row color
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, I'm passing the row and column index of the changed cell, so how can I take that and compare it to the specific row and/or cell in the unchanged DataSet?

**UPDATE**

Nocturnal reminded me that I need to allow for sorting of the DGV, so using row indexes won't work. He offered this as a solution (changed slightly to work with my objects):

```
If Not dsChanged Is Nothing Then
    For Each dtrow As DataRow In dsChanged.Tables("employees").Rows
        If DirectCast(dtrow, EmployeesDataSet.employeesRow).employeeID.ToString = dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("employeeID").Value.ToString Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To dsChanged.Tables("employees").Columns.Count - 1
                If Not dtrow(i, DataRowVersion.Current).Equals(dtrow(i, DataRowVersion.Original)) Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Employees ID: " & DirectCast(dtrow, EmployeesDataSet.employeesRow).employeeID)
                    dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.LightPink
                Else
                    ' Need to change the BackColor back to what it should be based on its original alternating row color
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End If
```

However, I'm getting an error on the `If DirectCast...` line saying "Column named "employeeID" cannot be found." I'm not sure if the error is on the DataSet or on the DGV, but there is an employeeID column in the database and DataSet. There *is* an employeeID as a bound column for the DataGridView, but it is set to Visible = False. That's the only thing I can think of that could possibly cause that error, but if it's a bound column, I would think it could be compared against as in this case.

**FINAL WORKING VERSION**

```
Private Sub dgvEmployees_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvEmployees.CellValueChanged
    ' Pass the row and cell indexes to the method so we can change the color of the edited row
    CompareDgvToDataSource("employees", e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub CompareDgvToDataSource(ByVal dataSetName As String, ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal columnIndex As Integer)
    ' Takes a dataset and the row and column indexes, checks if the row is different from the DataSet and colors the row appropriately

    EmployeesBindingSource.EndEdit()

    Dim dsChanges As DataSet = EmployeesDataSet.GetChanges()

    If Not dsChanges Is Nothing Then
        For Each dtrow As DataRow In dsChanges.Tables("employees").Rows
            If DirectCast(dtrow, EmployeesDataSet.employeesRow).employeeID.ToString = dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("employeeID").Value.ToString Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To dsChanges.Tables("employees").Columns.Count - 1

                    If dtrow.RowState.ToString = DataRowState.Added.ToString Then
                        ' TODO: Color entire new row
                    ElseIf dsChanges.Tables(dataSetName).Rows(0).HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Original) Then
                        If Not dtrow(i, DataRowVersion.Current).Equals(dtrow(i, DataRowVersion.Original)) Then
                            Console.WriteLine("Employees ID: " & DirectCast(dtrow, EmployeesDataSet.employeesRow).employeeID)
                            dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.LightPink
                        Else
                            ' TODO: Need to change the BackColor back to what it should be based on its original alternating row color
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

My project has four DGVs in it, so this will eventually be expanded to allow for all four DGVs to be checked for changes.

Comment: if you want to check only the row that has been changed you need to do this with the Tables ID and not the indexes

Comment: @Nocturnal - "Tables ID" - which table the DataTable?, the source DB table? Could you provide some sort of an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this approach it is simlar but only iterating the specific Table

`Private Sub dgvEmployees_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvEmployees.CellValueChanged
        ' Pass the row and cell indexes to the method so we can change the color of the edited row
        CompareDgvToDataSource(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex, sender.DataSource.datamember.ToString)
    End Sub`

and comparing the ID of the given Table

```
    Private Sub CompareDgvToDataSource(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal columnIndex As Integer, tablename As String)

    EmployeesBindingSource.EndEdit()

    Dim dsChanged As DataSet = EmployeesDataSet.GetChanges()

    If Not dsChanged Is Nothing Then
        For Each dtrow As DataRow In dsChanged.Tables(tablename).Rows

            If DirectCast(dtrow, EmployeesDataSet.EmployeeRow).EmployeeID = dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("EmployeeID").Value Then
                Dim currentColor As System.Drawing.Color = dgvEmployees.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor

                For i As Integer = 0 To dsChanged.Tables(tablename).Columns.Count - 1
                    If Not dtrow(i, DataRowVersion.Current).Equals(dtrow(i, DataRowVersion.Original)) Then
                        Console.WriteLine("Employees ID: " & DirectCast(dtrow, EmployeesDataSet.EmployeeRow).EmployeeID)
                        ' This works
                        dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.LightPink
                    Else
                        ' Need to change the BackColor back to what it should be based on its original alternating row color
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

and i am only changing the backcolor of the cell that was changed not the entire row....but depends how you would use that information anyways

EDIT:

with

```
Console.WriteLine(EmployeesDataSet.Employee(rowIndex)(columnIndex, DataRowVersion.Original).ToString())
Console.WriteLine(EmployeesDataSet.Employee(rowIndex)(columnIndex, DataRowVersion.Current).ToString())
```

you can see Current and Original Values
123456

Comment: Thanks for the sample, Nocturnal - I put that code in my project (adjusting a couple of things to remove errors). I noticed that you're specifically comparing just one column (employeeID in this case) - I'll need to iterate through the entire row to compare each DGV cell to the DataTable cell. Unless I'm missing something here...

Comment: yes i didn't change that part of your code it is still checking every cell Current with Original to see if there were changes and then highlighting that cell. maybe i misunderstood your question... you now have the ID and the Columindex and now you can check that information in your Dataset

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you, but I don't need a record's ID specifically, and as you know I have the DGV's row and column index, and with that can get the column name if necessary. I'm assuming I should be able to take that info (row/column indexes) and after getting the DataRow, using the DGV row index somehow, from the DataTable in the changed DataSet and check the cell value either matching the columnIndex or the column name.

Comment: the problem is what you get from the grid as rowindex or columnindex is not the same as the index in the underlying dataset table... thats why i suggested the ID because no matter how the grid is sorted or the dataset query to fill is ordered you have a primary key to work with ^^ indexes won't help you

Comment: Yes, I wasn't considering reordering - rowIndexes won't work then. Please see my updated question, if you could.

Comment: i edited my answer maybe that will help / and your EmployeeID problem is DGV problem u have to go to edit ID column and rename the Column to the same name .... dgv automatically gives a name like DataGriviewTextBoxCell1 or similar ... just change the name to appropriate one

Comment: This now works - mostly :) When a new row is added and another row is edited (doesn't matter which happened first) during the iteration for the second changed event I get a VersionNotFoundException, saying "There is no Original data to access." on the comparison If/Then line. I'm guessing it has something to do with the indexes, but if so, what?

Comment: yes for added rows ther is no Original State Value u can read that up here http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ww3k31w0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and you can see an example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datarowview.rowversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: For the record, I got around the new row/edited row problem by checking the DataRowState (for Added and Modified) and coded for each condition.

Comment: just edit your first post and show us the solution ... glad you sorted it out